# Output of xrandr shows 1024x768+1366+0; what does it mean and can I change it?

Tags: screen, xrandr

```
$ xrandr
VGA1 connected 1024x768+1366+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
```

I don't understand what the number 1366 in `1024x768+1366+0` represents. Can I change its value?

Comment: Are you using a dual-monitor setup? 1366 is horizontal offset of that display.

Comment: Yes, i'm using a dual-monitor setup. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Muru mentions, the `1366` is the horizontal offset of your screen.

#### How to read the output of xrandr

An example:

[image]

Imagine your two screens, placed together into a frame. Together, they will make a virtual screen as you can see above. In the output of `xrandr`, the left screen shows: `1680x1050+0+347`. The last two figures; `+0+347` show the `x` and `y` distance (px) of the upper left corner of the *screen*, to the upper left corner of the virtual *frame* they are in.

The right screen shows `1280x1024+1680+0`. The `+1680+0` shows similar information, as you can see in the image

#### Can You change these values?

Within boundaries, yes. An example to make both screens top-alligned:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --pos 0x0
```

Where DVI-I-1 is my left screen

This will create the situation as below:

[image]

More on the options of xrandr [here](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html).

Comment: Valuable explanation, thanks for the Figures - they help a lot. Just being curious, does have sense put a horizontal separation between the screens? - how a delta separation. For example in your both Figures exists a delta separation about the vertical positions