# How can I automatically switch off my internal screen on startup if an external monitor is connected?

Tags: multiple-monitors, 15.10, screen, xrandr

Solution anyone for a newb? I connect my notebook to external monitor with HDMI. I switch off screen notebook since I'm not using it. Ubuntu 15.04 remembered this setting after reboot, but with 15.10 I have to change this setting every time. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is the monitor always connected?

Comment: yes, it is always conneced. and switched on before i boot.

Comment: Just posted my answer. Let me know if you manage!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is pretty sure the result of a bug, but easily fixed on log in.

#### What to do

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `set_screen.py`

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import time

   #--- set the name of your internal screen below
   internal = "DVI-I-1"
   #---

   time.sleep(10)

   extr = [l.split()[0] for l in subprocess.check_output("xrandr").decode("utf-8").splitlines() if " connected" in l\
          and not internal in l]
   if extr:
       subprocess.Popen(["xrandr", "--output", internal, "--off", "--output", extr[0], "--auto"])
   ```
2. Get your internal screen's name: open a terminal window: press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and type the command

   ```
   xrandr
   ```

   and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Among the lines in the output, there is one line looking like:

   ```
   DVI-I-1 connected 1680x1050+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y
   ```

   You need to look at the first string, like `DVI-I-1`, this is your internal screen's name (obviously, you do not pick the one with `HDMI` in it :) )
3. Enter the name you found in the head of the script, in the line:

   ```
   internal = "DVI-I-1"
   ```

   between quotes, like in the example.
4. Test- run the script with the command (again, from the terminal window):

   ```
   python3 /path/to/set_screen.py
   ```

   (where you obviously need to replace `/path/to` by the actual path)
   After ten seconds, the internal screen should shut down, while the external screen stays.
5. If all works fine, add it to Startup Applications: open Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/set_screen.py
   ```

From now on, within a few seconds after log in, your internal screen will shut down.

Comment: thank you. I will give it a try, hopefully tonight. surprised that a work-around is necessary. curious to find out if this will also change the desktop size at the same time (which in fact is the reason that I manually have to switch off the internal screen)

Comment: @FrankThuis Ah, you didn't mention that. If the resolution is incorrect, you need to post the outpu of xrandr with a correct screen setup.

Comment: Your script works flawlessly when I run it manually. Even the desktop size seems to be fine.  [internal = "LVDS" & /usr/bin/set_screen.py ]. It doesnt seem to be working on startup and I still have to enter my password on the internal screen, but hey, its a work-around and beggars cannot be choosers. Maybe sth. with rights, but a link on somewhere works just as fine. So all in all, thank you. You gained an admirer.

Comment: I have done so. (And will do likewise in the future.) Thanks again.

Comment: @FrankThuis The internal screen should indeed switch off *after* log in, since Startup Applications works on log in. If it doesn't within 10 seconds or so, you need to increase the time in the line `time.sleep(10)` to (e.g.) `time.sleep(15)`

Comment: An alternative: http://askubuntu.com/questions/740004/how-can-i-automatically-switch-off-internal-screen-when-an-external-screen-is-co/740140#740140 This works also if you disconnect / connect again the screen.