# How can I make my left/right monitor configuration stick after a restart

Tags: login, multiple-monitors, display, xrandr, restart

Every time I start my PC, my leftmost monitor is configured to be my rightmost one. It works fine after I change it in display settings.

However, whenever I restart my PC, they're back to the wrong configuration. Is there a file I can edit that will force them to a certain configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monitor configurations on second monitors, as set in *Monitors*, often are not remembered after restart.

With the script below, you can define which of your monitors should be the left one on startup. It will top alline both monitors in a left/right setup.

The used commands are `xrandr` commands to position the screens in the spanning area of the two screens (see the link in "Notes").

#### Script to set up left/right monitor on startup

Since the commands to run depend on the current situation and which of your screens you actually want to have on the right/left, you'll need a script to check your screens, their horizontal resolutions, create the correct commands and automatically set up the desired situation on startup.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import sys

left = sys.argv[1]

# get the data on screens and resolutions, parsed from xrandr
current = [l.split() for l in subprocess.check_output(["xrandr"]).decode("utf-8").splitlines()]
# find the name(s), x-res of the screen(s)
screens = [
    (l[l.index("connected")-1], [s.split("x")[0] for s in l if s.count("+") == 2][0]) \
    for l in current if "connected" in l
    ]
# set up screen positions from left to right (important)
if left == screens[0][0]:
    subprocess.call(["xrandr", "--output", screens[0][0], "--pos", "0x0"])
    subprocess.call(["xrandr", "--output", screens[1][0], "--pos", screens[0][1]+"x0"])
elif left == screens[1][0]:
    subprocess.call(["xrandr", "--output",  screens[1][0], "--pos", "0x0"])
    subprocess.call(["xrandr", "--output",  screens[0][0], "--pos", screens[1][1]+"x0"])
```

#### How to use it

1. Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `setup_monitors.py`
2. Open a terminal window, run the command `xrandr`
3. In the output, two lines (if your second monitor is connected) will contain the names of your "connected" screens. The names look like: `DVI-I-1` or `VGA-0`. Make an educated guess which is the one you want on the left.
4. Run the script (from a terminal) by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/setup_monitors.py <left_screen>
   ```

   e.g.:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/setup_monitors.py DVI-I-1
   ```

   Test the command on both screens. The screens will black out for a second and be configurated.
5. If all works fine, add a command to your Startup Applications: choose Dash > Startup Applications > Add the command

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /path/to/setup_monitors.py DVI-I-1"
   ```

#### Note

- The sleep is specifically needed for `xrandr` commands when a second monitor is involved. If the script (actually the commands inside it) run too early, the desktop is not fully loaded yet and the commands will either break or miss their target.
- See also [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/614242/72216) for more info on what the command(s) inside the script are doing.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for 3 screens? Using it right now changes nothing that I can see.

Comment: @Backbounds Absolutely, five if you like. I can edit in an addition to the answer. I will be busy today and tomorrow however, but will get back to you, *and* I will need your help to test, since I can post an answer that *should* work, but my humble system only offers to connect two screens :)

Answer (score 1):

Jacob's solution works but there are some additional alternatives. You could put the `xrandr` commands in your `.xsessionrc` file, so that they're executed at startup. You could also just write an `xorg.conf` entry to set your monitors explicitly left/right of each other. I'm not at my PC so I'm regrettably short on details at the moment, but will come back to fill them in later if I get time. In the meantime it would be worthwhile for you to read up on both `xrandr` and `xorg.conf` files in general; you might discover a better solution than what I end up putting here anyway. ^_^

**EDIT:** OK I'm finally getting around to this.

### Using `xrandr` and `~/.xsessionrc`

The `xrandr` utility is used to both get and set information about your displays. Type `xrandr` by itself on the command line and you'll get a listing of all your displays and the "modes" that they support. Here is some example output corresponding to an old Dell 4:3 LCD.

```
DP2 connected 1280x1024+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 338mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1
```

You would add modes to these if your monitor's resolution isn't right, etc., but your problem is about positioning. `xrandr` provides simple parameters `--left-of <output>` and `--right-of <output>` that allow you to dictate where your displays sit in relation to each other.

So let's say your displays identify as `FOO1` and `FOO2`. (They never will; this is just an example.) If you want `FOO1` to be always on the left of `FOO2`, you would enter:

```
xrandr --output FOO1 --left-of FOO2
```

or

```
xrandr --output FOO2 --right-of FOO1
```

Typing this on the command line will immediately make the change for your current session. Inserting the same line into your `~/.xsessionrc` file will make the change effective every time you start X.

### Using `xorg.conf`

Your other alternative is to write an `xorg.conf` entry that will dictate display configuration as part of the X startup process. If you're on Ubuntu then this will likely be part of a file in an `xorg.conf.d` *directory*, either at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d` or `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`. So if you don't already have one, create a config file to drive your display adapters and monitors. I called mine `01-monitors.conf` to ensure it got executed first. Reusing the previous example with `FOO1` being to the left of `FOO2`, we can set up the same preference here with a `Monitor` config section.

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "FOO1"
    Option "LeftOf" "FOO2"
EndSection
```

Note that the `Identifier` is the same one you'd get from `xrandr`.

#### Further Reading

The `man` page for the `xorg.conf` configuration system is available at http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.7/doc/man/man5/xorg.conf.5.xhtml