# 14.04, 3 screens in portrait, adjustment to be done each reboot

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, nvidia-settings, xorg.conf, orientation

[image]

Every time I reboot my screens are like this, with a space in between them. My xorg.conf file does not get overwritten each time since the content is identical from one boot to the other (xorg.conf identical to xorg.conf.backup). So changing the file attribute to +i does not change a thing. Modifying grub file with nogpumanager either. If I log out and log in, my screen config is still OK. Problem occurs only when I reboot.

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 331.20
```

The correct line is there:

```
Option "metamodes" "DVI-I-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {rotation=left}, DP-1: nvidia-auto-select +1024+0 {rotation=left}, DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +2048+0 {rotation=left}"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Would you be helped if the screen setup was automated *after login*?

Comment: Better than nothing...

Comment: Works great, edited the script to left \ and not left\

Comment: @Houba If you want to mark a question as solved, accept an answer instead of adding "[SOLVED]" to the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Automatically arrange your screens on log in

The fact that your screen setup is not remembered on restart (re- login) is most likely the result of a minor incompatibility between your screen(s) and the graphics driver. To work around:

If I made no typo or mistake, the command:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --pos 0x0 --rotation left --output DP-1 --pos 1024x0 --rotation left --output DVI-D-0 --pos 2048x0 --rotation left
```

...should make your screen setup

#### How to add to startup applications

1. Copy the code below into an empty file, save it as `setup_screens.sh`, and *make it executable*

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --pos 0x0 --rotation left \
   --output DP-1 --pos 1024x0 --rotation left \
   --output DVI-D-0 --pos 2048x0 --rotation left
   ```
2. Test-run the script by the command:

   ```
   /path/to/setup_screens.sh
   ```
3. If all works fine, add to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && /path/to/setup_screens.sh"
   ```

#### Explanation

The explanation on why and how can be found on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/779887/72216). The sleep 15 is to make sure the desktop is "ready" before the setup is done.

#### Is this question a dupe?

Yes and no:

- Yes, there are many almost similar questions on screen setup (not) being persistent.
- No, not a *literal* dupe, since all situations are slightly different.

If you are not familiar with `xrandr` commands, reading the (almost) dupes does not help you much, therefore I'd still write an answer to help out in this specific situation.

Comment: The command provided works, add a space after left before the slash left \ otherwise you will have an error.